# How to use Imports System.Xml in Open Office (Basic)?

Tags: xml, openoffice.org, basic, openoffice-calc, openoffice-basic

Whenever I place `Imports System.Xml` above the rest of the code I get an error:
*BASIC syntax error. Expected: Sub.*

And when I place it inside any of the Subs I get another error:
*BASIC syntax error. Unexpected symbol: Stop.*

Are we even able to use `Imports` in the code in Open Office?
Or do I need to import in one of the menus?

Comment: OpenOffice.org is obsolete. LibreOffice is mostly used now, and there is also Apache OpenOffice which strives to maintain a traditional (older) way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

From my google search, `Imports System.Xml` is for .NET technologies. Is StarBasic a .NET technology? No.

You can create projects in C# or VB.Net that use LibreOffice's UNO API.

Or maybe you want to know how to work with XML in a LibreOffice macro. In that case, there are many different answers. Personally I would create a Python-UNO macro and start with `import xml.etree`. Alternatively, the UNO API provides access to the powerful XML libraries built into LibreOffice.